# Send intent withing a piece of Java code

Tags: android-intent, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, chat

Here's a piece of code of Bluetooth Chat:

```
        public void run() {
        byte[] buffer;
        ArrayList<Integer> arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                int data = mmInStream.read();
                if(data == 0x0A) { 
                } else if(data == 0x0D) {
                    buffer = new byte[arr_byte.size()];
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_byte.size() ; i++) {
                        buffer[i] = arr_byte.get(i).byteValue();

                    }


                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothState.MESSAGE_READ
                            , buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                } else {
                    arr_byte.add(data);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start(BluetoothService.this.isAndroid);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to send an intent to a broadcast receiver with content of buffer. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
            public void run() {
        byte[] buffer;
        ArrayList<Integer> arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                int data = mmInStream.read();
                if(data == 0x0A) { 
                } else if(data == 0x0D) {
                    buffer = new byte[arr_byte.size()];
                    for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_byte.size() ; i++) {
                        buffer[i] = arr_byte.get(i).byteValue();

                    }

                    ***Intent intent = new Intent(DATA_RECEIVED_INTENT); 
                    intent.putExtra(DATA_EXTRA, buffer); 
                    sendBroadcast(intent);*** 

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(BluetoothState.MESSAGE_READ
                            , buffer.length, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
                    arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                } else {
                    arr_byte.add(data);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothService.this.start(BluetoothService.this.isAndroid);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I get error:

> cannot resolve method sendBroadcast(Intent)

I understand that this method should be defined in Activity (maybe?) or it's totally incorrect way of sending intent. Is there a way around this?